# Django Login Custom Auth works locally but not on production server

Tags: python, django, authentication

I implemented a custom Authentication Backend for my Django Project. If I run Django locally, accessing the productive database, everything works properly.
But if I run the same Django App on the production server, It fails.

Here is my custom Authentication:

```
import hashlib
import logging

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from QAServer import error_codes
from QAServer import exceptions
from QAServer.DataAccess.UserDAO import UserDAO
from QAServer.couchbase_util import ConnectionUtil

import constants as c

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class CouchbaseBackend(object):
    _workaround_delimiter = "login+"

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # ## workaround to suppress 401 responses when login+ is provided in username
        # ## -> otherwise problem with browser behaviour!
        if username.find(CouchbaseBackend._workaround_delimiter) >= 0:
            split = username.split(CouchbaseBackend._workaround_delimiter)
            username = split[1]

        salt, user = self.get_user(username)

        if salt:
            pass_hash = hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
        else:
            pass_hash = hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()

        logger.debug(user.details)
        # ## authentication fallback
        if user.password == pass_hash:
            logger.debug(user.details)
            return user
        else:
            logger.info("### wrong password for user %s ###" % username)
            raise exceptions.PermissionError(error_code=error_codes.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDED)

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            con = ConnectionUtil.get_prod_instance()
            dao = UserDAO(con)

            cb_user = dao.find_by_username(username)

            return self.convert_to_django_user(cb_user)
        except User.DoesNotExist as e:
            logger.error("### Get User Error (Couchbase Backend Authentication) ###")
            logger.error(e)
            logger.error("#########################################################")
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def convert_to_django_user(cb_user):
        user_name = cb_user[c.USERNAME]
        email = cb_user[c.EMAIL]
        password = cb_user[c.PASSWORD]
        salt = cb_user.get(c.SALT, None)
        user = None

        try:
            user = User(username=user_name, password=password)
            user.email = email
            user.username = user_name
            user.details = cb_user

        except Exception, e:
            logger.error("### convert user to django user ###")
            logger.error(e)
            logger.error("###################################")
        return salt, user
```

Part of my settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'QASystem.couchbase_backend.CouchbaseBackend'
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'QASystemBackend',
    'QASystem'
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'QASystem.Authentication.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'QASystem.exception_handler.exception_handler',
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

My Login View:

```
class LoginSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_dao = UserDAO(CBaseUtil.get_prod_instance())
        self.token_dao = LoginTokenDAO(CBaseUtil.get_prod_instance())

    def login(self, request):
        if IsAuthenticated().has_permission(request, None):
            user = self.user_dao.find_by_key(request.user.details[m.ID])

            logger.info("LoginView::get Login UserID: %s" % request.user.details[m.ID])

            response_obj = {
                m.USER: user_models.UserModelParser.prepare_response(user),
                m.LOGIN_TOKEN: self.token_dao.create_token_for_user(user[m.ID])[0]
            }

            return Response(response_obj)
        else:
            logger.error("LoginView::get Invalid Credentials UserID")
            raise exceptions.PermissionError(error_code=error_codes.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDED)
```

Here in the login view when I set a breakpoint, locally it shows the correct User Object in `request.user` but on production, it keeps saying, that it is an anonymous user.

The part where it fails is the `IsAuthenticated().hasPermission(request, None)` as apparently the permission is not given here or IsAuthenticated resolves to False.

Any idea, what I might got wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, that mod_wsgi caused the problem, as it is not passing the authorization by default.

For all others, that experience the problem, see this section of the djangorestframework:

**Apache mod_wsgi specific configuration**

Note that if deploying to Apache using `mod_wsgi`, the authorization header is not passed through to a WSGI application by default, as it is assumed that authentication will be handled by Apache, rather than at an application level.

If you are deploying to Apache, and using any non-session based authentication, you will need to explicitly configure `mod_wsgi` to pass the required headers through to the application. This can be done by specifying the `WSGIPassAuthorization` directive in the appropriate context and setting it to `'On'`.

```
# this can go in either server config, virtual host, directory or .htaccess
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```